# django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError Migration authentication nonexistent parent node

Tags: django, django-models

I was running my code on django and i ran into this problem. What might be the issue? I am using django 2.0.2

```
  Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f6ead6dcea0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 244, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 261, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/geek/PycharmProjects/hadhari/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 104, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration authentication.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. I did go into `django/django/contrib/auth/migrations/` and realized that the migration files were missing.

From this, I realized that I had to uninstall django and re-installed
it, you will no longer get the bug.