# django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError while upgrading django

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, django-migrations, django-1.5, django-1.11

I am upgrading my django project from `django1.5` to `django1.11.10`. while upgrading when I run `./manange.py migrate` I am getting `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError`

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration account.0004_auto_20180419_1309 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'admin', u'0003_advertisements_alignedcourses_api_integration_appreciation_certificate_company_company_types_contrib')`enter code here`
```

This is my project structure

[image]

admin/apps.py

```
class AdminConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.admin'
    label = 'admin_app'
```

account/apps.py

```
class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'account'
    label = 'account_app'
```

And I have added meta property for all admin models

```
class Meta:
'''
        Meta properties for this model
'''
    app_label = 'admin_app'
```

I could not find any migration files from my project  and I followed some of the solution which I found in internet.

[django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError Migration authentication nonexistent parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344433/django-db-migrations-exceptions-nodenotfounderror-migration-authentication-nonex)

[Can't get rid of "nonexistent parent node" in django 1.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124207/cant-get-rid-of-nonexistent-parent-node-in-django-1-11)

I reinstalled django.Deleted all `.pyc` files. deleted all migrations files. Still I am getting the same error.Please help me and can you please explain why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have apps with the same name - your own app called `admin` and `django.contrib.admin`. No mater what is the full python path to the app final part is important part and need to be unique across the project.

You can try to change the `label` of the `AppConfig` of your applications which conflict with django's or other 3th party apps.

Look at the Django docs 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label

> **AppConfig.label**
>
> Short name for the application, e.g. 'admin'
>
> This attribute allows relabeling an application when two applications have conflicting labels. It defaults to the last component of name. It should be a valid Python identifier.
>
> It must be unique across a Django project.

and in the Django's source code https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/apps/config.py#L31-L34

```
# Last component of the Python path to the application eg. 'admin'.
# This value must be unique across a Django project.
if not hasattr(self, 'label'):
    self.label = app_name.rpartition(".")[2]
```

Comment: I have already changed `label` of the `AppConfig`. Still I am getting the error. I have updated my question.

Comment: Then probably you need to find the file `0004_auto_20180419_1309.py` or `0004_auto_20180419_1309.pyc`. You need to see where this file is located

Answer (score 0):

okay i found the answers chances are u guys are using venv(python virtual enviroment) please delete that folder and delete all your migrations folder...

After u done that create a new venv and install all ur stuff and run ur usual migration commands

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i just ran into thi problem and i sloved it.. it as tricky but the key is not in your code.. the key is in your virtual enviroment .. if u are not using a virtual environment then this anwser is not for you

**1) Delete your virtual enviroment (first option)**

**2) look at your command line were your django server is ...**

```
  search your venv for this "0003_advertisements_alignedcourses_api_integration_appreciation_certificate_company_company_types_contrib.py"
```

if you find it just delete the migration folder that houses this file
that all bruv